# Tool for viewing available DBUS messages I can send to an application

Tags: gui, dbus

Is there a graphical tool or maybe a command-line one that lists all the messages and parameters/arguments that I can send to a DBUS-enabled program?? I really want to try scripting some DBUS things but I can hardly find any documentation for the DBUS capabilities of most applications.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## DBUS Message/Signal Viewer Tools

- [qdbus-viewer-qt4](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/qt-qdbusviewer)
- [dbus-monitor](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html)
- [Bustle](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bustle/bustle)
- [d-feet](http://live.gnome.org/DFeet/)

Answer (score 61):

Have you tried [d-feet](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/d-feet/):

```
sudo apt-get install d-feet
```

[Homepage](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DFeet)

Answer (score 7):

Another useful D-Bus debugging and profiling tool is [Bustle](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bustle/bustle).

Comment: From the link, it looks like this cannot list potential commands, as per the question.

Answer (score 7):

For Kubuntu users, KDE ships with `qdbusviewer-qt4`, which can list all available commands to all dbus clients.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: for the newest distributions of kubuntu, use qdbusviewer which is from the qdbus-qt5 package (to access qdbus-qt5) and for the  qdbusviewer itself you need qttools5-dev-tools. You can still get the old one in qt4-dev-tools if you must have qt4 compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using `dbus-monitor`, which is really useful. It provides a `--profile` mode, which provides a quick summary of all the signals bouncing around.

Comment: I don't think this can list potential commands, as per the question.

Answer (score 0):

[*D-Feet* is no longer maintained](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DFeet). *D-Feet* themselves suggest to use [***D-Spy***](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/d-spy) (also spelled ***d-spy***).

- GUI-based *D-Spy* can be used to **discover all *available*** D-Bus bus names, interfaces, signals and methods, as well as **execute methods and query for properties**.

  - Installation via *flatpak*: [`flatpak install flathub org.gnome.dspy`](https://flathub.org/apps/org.gnome.dspy)
- GUI-based [*Bustle*](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/bustle) can be used to **capture/record *ongoing* D-Bus activity, including method invocations and emitted signals**. After recording, the activity is presented as a sequence diagram.

  - Installation via *flatpak*: [`flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Bustle`](https://flathub.org/apps/org.freedesktop.Bustle)